# Laravel custom form request redirecting to index page

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

I've created a custom form request with `php aritisan make:request`, I have added in validation rules:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|string',
            'last_name' => 'required|string',
            ...
            'email' => 'email|unique:auth_user,email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)],
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ];
    }
```

However, it redirects me to the index page. This is my function:

```
public function store(RegistrationFormRequest $request)
{
    return dd($request);
}
```

My `POST` request doesn't actually have any parameters, so I already assumed that it wont reach the `dd` function but instead send a `422` error as it fails the validation. But it doesn't, instead it redirects me to the `/` page on my `web.php` routes.

Here's the structure:

api.php:

`Route::post('auths/register', [UserController::class, 'store']);`

Controller:

```
public function store(RegistrationFormRequest $request)
{
    return dd($request);
}
```

Custom form request class:

```
class RegistrationFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => 'required|string',
            'last_name' => 'required|string',
            'middle_name' => 'required|string',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric|size:10',
            'region' => 'exists:base_addressoption,name',
            'province' => 'exists:base_addressoption,name',
            'city' => 'exists:base_addressoption,name',
            'brgy' => 'exists:base_addressoption,name',
            'street' => 'required|string',
            'address1' => 'required|string',
            'zip_code' => 'required|numeric',
            'address2' => 'nullable|string',
            'email' => 'email|unique:auth_user,email',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::min(8)],
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:8',
        ];
    }
}
```

It works when I add in all the parameters, but that I need to validate when a parameter isn't present. It needs to return an error `422`.

More info. Using the regular `Request` works but not when using my own form request

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return dd($request);
}
```

Comment: @JohnLobo I need it to be true. It's a public route. It needs to be true. If I set it to false then I have to authenticate a user or something. It's a publicly accessible route for customer's that gonna register.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer later on. It's an API route request, but Laravel behaves as if it's a regular web route.

So if you're testing in Postman, add `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` in the header so Laravel knows its an XHR request.

Answer (score 1):

Im using Postman to send posts requests to my api in laravel and all i need is to put `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` in Headers to prevent redirections